# Remove border gap in HTML doc

Tags: html, css, border

I am learning HTML, and I've created a dead-simple page with a header bar, but there is a gap between the header and the sides & top of the page for some reason, shown in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfKxW.png)

Is there a way to remove this?
Code:`<!doctype html>

```
<style>

    html {
        background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 800px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: grey;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    }

    /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }


</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
```

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="default">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html has a default margin and padding value for every container. So your heading is using it as you haven't explicitly specified.

So, you can set the defaults to 0, and there will be no gap as shown below -

```
<style>

        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

</style>
```